Battery under dryer
I’ve dropped two AAA batteries that rolled under my washer and/or dryer in the laundry room. I cannot move my Appliances since They are pushed up against The walls on three sides. I cannot see under them so I don’t know where it is. I’ve tried using a yardstick And one of them rolled out from under the dryer. But I absolutely cannot find the other battery. How can I, get this battery out from under the appliance and if I cannot. Is it safe to stay under my washer or dryer?

If you can get a yardstick under, can't you get one eye at floor level and look under (with a flashlight)? In time, the battery will leak chemicals.
